# Stat block from Animate Dead

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, undead

When I use Animate Dead from the corpse of fallen NPCs (and maybe PC), **how to decide the stat block?**

Do they use the original stat block? Should they have penalty (because they start rotting)? Do they keep their mental ability scores? Do they keep their features?

> *the DM has the creature's game statistics*

is this referring to the monster Skeleton and Zombie, or to "DM decide the stats"?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is answered in the spell's description:

> The target becomes a **skeleton** if you chose bones or a **zombie** if you chose a corpse (the DM has the creature's game statistics).

Referring to the skeleton and zombie stat block in the Monster Manual.

If the DM was meant to choose the statistics it would specifically say so, such as with the Awaken spell:

> Your DM chooses statistics appropriate for the awakened plant, such as the statistics for the awakened shrub or the awakened tree.

Answer (score 13):

**Who the corpse was does not matter**. *Animate dead* states:

> The target becomes a skeleton if you chose bones or a zombie if you
>   chose a corpse (PHB 212)

These are *not* creature types, they refer to specific creatures with stat blocks included in the MM. Equipment might modify that, but the base creature is the same.

Answer (score 8):

Animate Dead specifically states that

> The target becomes a **skeleton** if you chose bones or a **zombie** if you
>   choose a corpse (the DM has the creature's statistics).

**Emphasis mine**

In the Monster Manual you can find stat blocks for "Skeleton" on page 272 and "Zombie" on page 316